# Do I need to make up these fasts/prayers?

Tags: salat, practical-islam, sawm

I have been fasting but I skipped my prayers for a few days out of laziness and due to some personal things going on. I regret doing this and I just want to know if I need to make up the fasts and prayers for these days or offer any expiation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make up the prayers missed not the fasts unless you broke the fast in which case you have to make up the fasts